# Independent features but PCA improves classifiers accuracy significantly. Why?

Tags: pca, accuracy, k-nearest-neighbour, high-dimensional

that's my first question on here :)

I am working with the kNN classifier on datasets from the multivariate normal distribution. I have to groups coming from  `N(mu_1,I)` and `N(mu_2,I)` with differing expectation vectors `mu_i` and both identity matrices as covariances (so the features are independent). The dimension is 1000. One dataset constitutes of 3500 entries of random draws from group 1 and 1500 random draws from group 2. I want to study kNN's performance on such high-dimensional data for different configurations of the `mu_i`.

Obviously, I struggle with the curse of dimensionality, but that is the goal.
Still just for fun, I did a PCA projection onto the first two components, so effectively a reduction to 2 dimension, and the classifiers accuracy improved about 10%.
How come? My features are independent. Shouldn't that make PCA unsuitable?

**Edit**: The dataset (1000 features, 5000 samples) are split into 70/30 train and test set. The accuracy is computed using the test set - so I suppose its an out-of-sample accuracy

I thank you in advance for enlightening me ;)

**Edit**: Here is the **R** code to generate the data

```
generate_data <- function(num_samples, num_features, group_split, mu_1) {
  split_samples <- num_samples * group_split
  Sigma <- diag(num_features)  # Covariance matrix
  mean_vector_1 <- rep(mu_1, num_features)
  mean_vector_2 <- rep(0, num_features)
  
  # Generating data for two groups
  data_1 <- mvrnorm(n = split_samples, mu = mean_vector_1, Sigma = Sigma)
  data_2 <- mvrnorm(n = num_samples - split_samples, mu = mean_vector_2, Sigma = Sigma)
  
  # Combine and label data
  data <- rbind(data_1, data_2)
  labels <- c(rep(1, split_samples), rep(2, num_samples - split_samples))
  
  return(as.data.frame(cbind(labels, data)))
}
```

This is the projection function I use before using a simply kNN-classifier:

```
projection <- function(dataset) {
  data_pca <- PCA(dataset[, -1], graph = FALSE)
  data.frame(labels = dataset[,1],
             PC1 = data_pca$ind$coord[,1], 
             PC2 = data_pca$ind$coord[,2])
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CV.  I don't know the answer but, since this is all simulated data anyway, it might help if you included all your code for people to play with.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Is this in-sample or out-of-sample accuracy?

Comment: @PeterFlom I added the code

Comment: @Dave I added this info. I use a test set to determine the accuracy. So it should be out-of-sample

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. What kind of in-sample accuracy do you get? I’m wondering if this is a simple case of overfitting.

Comment: without pca I get around 70% and with pca 85%

Comment: Even in-sample?